# How can I create a unique ID between 2 users?

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, visual-studio-2013, message

So I've been working on a C# encrypted messenger for fun, and it has the encryption/decryption sequence that needs to use a unique 45 character set.

I've created some just as demos, and the encryption works. But currently I'm adding a login system. When logged in, you get a list of people, and each person you talk to will have a unique conversation ID.

So basically, I want to find a way to create this conversation ID so that it is different for each use you have added, but the same for if another user adds you.

For example:
I add Bob and the ID for the conversation is: R4ToGdKknnFKZNucj8xvpoP30vagfhtIdyrrLnQG

Currently, if Bob adds me, the ID will be different. But I'm trying to find a way to make it the same between 2 users, but different between 2 other users.

If anyone can help, that'd be great. I'm using the encryption code provided by [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14150/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Data-with-C) but edited for my needs. If needed, I can post the code here. I'm using a C# Windows Form Application.

Comment: You could concat the two user id's in lexicographic order and then encrypt that into a conversation ID

Comment: What algorithm did you use to produce the conversation Id to start with (ie, how did you get `R4ToGdKknnFKZNucj8xvpoP30vagfhtIdyrrLnQG` from your Id and Bob's)?

Comment: It looks like your application requires server with a database. Create entity  named Conversation with its own id as well as user1Id and user2Id ...

Comment: @Jamiec I just used a random generator, so I don't know the algorithm. 
It's the one provided by LastPass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the usernames are consistent and unique, you could convert some string combination of them into a format more appropriate as an ID (such as the bigint this procedure creates):

```
string user1 = "daniel25";
string user2 = "kevin91";

var hashBuilder = new StringBuilder();
if (user1.CompareTo(user2) < 0)
{
   hashBuilder.Append(user1);
   hashBuilder.Append(user2);
}
else
{
   hashBuilder.Append(user2);
   hashBuilder.Append(user1);
}

var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(hashBuilder.ToString());
byte[] hashBytes;

using (var hasher = SHA1.Create())
{
    hashBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(bytes);
}

long value = BitConverter.ToInt64(hashBytes, 12);
var uniqueHash =  IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(value);
```

Store that ID as a bigint in your database and you have a primary key that references a conversation between two people, and is also easy to index and look up.

This method has some limitations (such as user "daniel25" an "kevin91" receiving the same hash as "daniel" and "25kevin91"), but I think you could work around them if you add a username 'separator' that is not allowable as a username character.

```
var hashBuilder = new StringBuilder();
hashBuilder.Append(user1);
hashBuilder.Append("@");
hashBuilder.Append(user2);
```

Also, no need to convert to an `Int64` if you want to just use a true hash - you can take `hashBytes` right into an nvarchar field.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for, I may change it a bit to mess around, but as it's not needing to be a super secure encryption, that sounds great. Thank you.

Comment: @PXgamer FYI I edited to include Alex H's suggestion of sorting the users before adding them.  This way the order of the user's won't affect the hash.

Comment: Omg. That is brilliant now :P Thank you. I was trying to work it out as when I changed user, the system broke. But now it's working great. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, both users don't know each other Conversation ID. If it could be generated easily, then everyone could generate it and the whole encryption is already unsecure by design. Here is some [example](http://www.cymbeline.ch/2014/02/28/dynamic-aes-key-exchange-through-rsa-encryption/) how this works in a client/server communication: First, RSA is used for asymmetric encryption of the communication to exchange the AES key, which is used for the symmetric encryption. The key is not permanent, it should change with every new conversation even if between the same users.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense as I don't want them to be easily guessed, but not sure how I could get them to record the same key. So far it's not really a messenger, more of a decrypt/encrypt system.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Chris Schubert's Answer:
When you add `string.CompareTo(string)` you will get the same hash for every pair.

And when you compare the values, you will have the exact same hash for every duplicate pair:

```
if (user1.CompareTo(user2) < 0)
{
   hashBuilder.Append(user1);
   hashBuilder.Append(user2);
}
else
{
   hashBuilder.Append(user2);
   hashBuilder.Append(user1);
}
```

This way it will not matter if kevin is user1 or daniel